# Probability theory of Vapnik

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, self-learning, poisson-process

What is a formula for covariance of poisson process

Comment: If we define $X$ by $X_t=(-1)^{N_t}$ for $t\geq 0$, you probably want to calculate $\text{Cov}(X_s,X_t)$ for $s,t\geq 0$ in order to solve a). Now what is $\text{Cov}(X_s,X_t)$? Notice that $X$ takes its values in $\{-1,1\}$.

Comment: "Now what is Cov(Xs,Xt)" this is the point I am lost ;)

Comment: $\text{Cov}(X_s,X_t)=E[X_sX_t]-E[X_s]E[X_t]$ (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance)

Comment: thanks for link, but fortunately  I know how to calculate covariance ;) I dont know how to calculate this particular covariance

Comment: Well, then you should have asked more detailled (for example how to calculate $E[(-1)^{N_s}]). Anyway, someone did your homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Y_t:=(-1)^{N_t}$ and $s<t$. Then
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}Y_t&=\mathsf{P}(N_t \text{ is even})-\mathsf{P}(N_t \text{ is odd}) \\
&=e^{-\lambda t}(\sinh(\lambda t)-\cosh(\lambda t))=e^{-2\lambda t}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}Y_tY_s&=\mathsf{P}(Y_t=1\mid Y_s=1)\mathsf{P}(Y_s =1) \\
&-\ldots \\
&+\mathsf{P}(Y_t=-1\mid Y_s=-1)\mathsf{P}(Y_s =-1)\\
&=e^{-2\lambda(t-s)}.
\end{align}
Thus,
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(Y_s,Y_t)=e^{-2\lambda(t-s)}-e^{-2\lambda t}e^{-2\lambda s}.
$$